# How can I modify what is being output in wp_head, whether by a theme or Wordpress in general?

Tags: plugins, performance, wp-head, core-modifications

I've been working on performance of my site using YSLOW, and noticed that Wordpress it outputting things in my document head that I know I don't need.

For example, I'm already calling jQuery 1.9 from the Google CDN, so I don't need the call to jQuery in wp-includes.

Also, a plugin is including a stylesheet which I don't need (because I'm overwriting 99% of those styles anyway in my theme), so I'd like to get rid of that call also.

So how do I edit what is being output by the `wp_head()` function, whether Wordpress is putting it there (like the `wp-includes` jQuery call) or whether a plugin is putting it there (like the stylesheet call)?

Answer (score 5):

First: **don't enqueue custom versions of WordPress core-bundled scripts**, including (and *especially*) jQuery.

Second, to answer your question: those Plugin scripts and stylesheets are *enqueued*, using [**`add_action()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action), via a callback hooked into one of the following action hooks:

- `wp_head`
- `wp_enqueue_scripts`
- `wp_print_scripts`
- `wp_print_styles`

(There are others, but those are the most likely.)

Inside the callback, the following functions are used to enqueue:

- Stylesheets: [**`wp_enqueue_style()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)
- Scripts: [**`wp_enqueue_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

So, for a Plugin-enqueued stylesheet, named `foobar.css`, you'd need to look in the Plugin files for calls to `wp_enqueue_style()`, then note the name of the callback function it is called within. Then, find the `add_action()` call that references that callback function. e.g.:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'pluginname_enqueue_styles' );
```

Once you've found that call, you can *override* it yourself, using [**`remove_action()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action):

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'pluginname_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that overriding default versions with a CDN-hosted version is a bad practice. The onus is on you, however, to ensure you're using a version which all of your plugins are compatible with. Be sure to test thoroughly.

To override the default jQuery with the CDN version, add something like this to your `functions.php` :

```
function replace_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'replace_jquery');
```